# Spring cache-control issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cache-control

I am building a web application in springboot. It is secured by springboot-security.I want to cache all my public resources such as images, javascript and css files, for let's say a week. I need everything else not to be cached since it contains sensitive data.

I've managed to get 304 code on all resources with these properties but I haven't been able to see cache control header on my networking tab in google chrome

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off 
spring.main.logStartupInfo=false
spring.resources.cache-period=86400
```

My first question is can this weaken or break spring-security somehow? Secondly how can i set cache control header?

I've been also digging the web and found these examples

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someAction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=86400");

    // ...
}
```

As far as I understood, these two options disable springboot security in some ways
Anyhow, I don't know how to combine them, or even if i should... These solutions give me 304 as well but All of these options give me

**The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:**

on tools.pingdom.com

Does anyone know how to set longer cache for public and static resources? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!